# I'm stuck with GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gurobi

Could you help me with the

> GurobiError: Unable to convert argument to an expression

I tried to declare variables as single variables (e.g x1, x2, x3 etc.), but then I thought the iterable objects will work better (as there was 'Non-itereable object' error), but still Gurobi cannot convert the expression; It now only throws an error at the #96, but I still can't find What should I do?

My code:

```
import gurobipy as grb

f = [5.5, 5.2, 5]
s = 3.8

lX = [0, 0, 0]
uX = [45000, 4000, 1000000]

lV = [0, 0]

lY = [0, 0]
uY = [1000000, 30000]

r = [3.25, 3.4]
pProc = 0.35
pConv = 0.25

p = [5.75, 4.0]

OreProcessingModel = grb.Model(name="MIP Model")
OreProcessingModel.ModelSense = grb.GRB.MAXIMIZE

x = {i: OreProcessingModel.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, 
                                  lb=lX[i], 
                                  ub= uX[i],
                                  name="x_{0}".format(i)) 
for i in range(3)}

v = {i: OreProcessingModel.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                  lb=lV[i],
                                  name="v_{0}".format(i))
for i in range(2)}

y = {i: OreProcessingModel.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS,
                                  lb=lY[i],
                                  ub=uY[i],
                                  name="v_{0}".format(i))
for i in range(2)}

conv = OreProcessingModel.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=0, ub=50000, name="conv")

vlms2 = [v[0], v[1]]
vlmsitrtr = 2


constraint_1 = {1:
OreProcessingModel.addConstr(
        lhs=grb.quicksum(y[i] for i in range(2)),
        sense=grb.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,
        rhs=100000,
        name="constraint_{1}")
}

constraint_2 = {1:
OreProcessingModel.addConstr(
        lhs=grb.quicksum(v[i] for i in range(2)),
        sense=grb.GRB.LESS_EQUAL,
        rhs=50000,
        name="constraint_{2}")
}

OreProcessingModel.setObjective(grb.quicksum((f[i] * x[i] + s * v[i]) - (y[i]*r[i] + pProc*(y[i]) + pConv*conv))for i in range(3))


OreProcessingModel.optimize()
print(OreProcessingModel)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not work with dictionaries like that. You can turn this code

```
x = {i: OreProcessingModel.addVar(vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, 
                                  lb=lX[i], 
                                  ub= uX[i],
                                  name="x_{0}".format(i)) 
for i in range(3)}
```

into this:

```
x = OreProcessingModel.addVars(len(lX), vtype=grb.GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=lX, ub=uX, name="x")
```

Furthermore, the dimensions of your variables don't match. You are looping over `range(3)` in the `setObjective()` call and try to access `v[i]` and `y[i]` but these dicts are only of length 2.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped!